# How do I reduce the running time of the code to justify text?

Tags: c++

This is the [Problem Statement](https://leetcode.com/problems/text-justification/#/description) in a nutshell:

> Given an array of words and a width maxWidth, format the text such that each line has exactly maxWidth characters and is fully (left and right) justified.
>   You should pack your words in a greedy approach; that is, pack as many words as you can in each line. Pad extra spaces ' ' when necessary so that each line has exactly maxWidth characters.
>   Extra spaces between words should be distributed as evenly as possible. If the number of spaces on a line do not divide evenly between words, the empty slots on the left will be assigned more spaces than the slots on the right.
>   For the last line of text, it should be left justified and no extra space is inserted between words.

This is the code I wrote to justify the text:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> getWords(std::string line) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    return std::vector<std::string>{ std::istream_iterator<std::string>{iss}, std::istream_iterator<std::string>{} };
}

std::vector<std::string> justifiedText(const std::vector<std::string>& text, const size_t& width) {
    std::vector<std::string> list_of_words;
    for (const auto& line : text) {
        auto words = getWords(line);
        for (const auto& word : words) {
            list_of_words.push_back(word);
        }
    }
    //divide into lines
    std::vector<std::string> justify;
    for (int i = 0; i < list_of_words.size(); i++) {
        std::string statement;
        while (statement.size() + list_of_words.at(i).size() <= width) {
            statement = statement + list_of_words.at(i) + " ";
            i++;
            if (i == list_of_words.size()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        statement.erase(--statement.end());
        justify.push_back(statement);
        i--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < justify.size() - 1; i++) {
        std::string& statement = justify.at(i);
        int j = 0;
        int extra_spaces = 0;
        while (statement.size() < 16) {
            if (statement.at(j) == ' ') {
                statement.insert(j, " ");
                j = j + ++extra_spaces;
            }
            j = j >= statement.size() - 1 ? 0 : j + 1;
        }
    }
    auto& statement = justify.back();
    while (statement.size() < 16) {
        statement += " ";
    }
    return justify;
}

int main() {
    //I/O is through file as my lazy ass finds it exhausting to type in the console over and over again :P
    std::ifstream infile("ip.txt");
    int width = 0;
    infile >> width;
    int count_of_lines = 0;
    infile >> count_of_lines;
    std::vector<std::string> text(count_of_lines);
    {
        std::string str;
        std::getline(infile, str, '\n');
    }
    for (auto& line : text) {
        std::getline(infile, line, '\n');
    }
    infile.close();
    text = justifiedText(text, width);
    std::ofstream outfile("output.txt");
    for (auto line : text) {
        outfile << line << "\n";
    }
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This code passes the test cases shown there, but exceeds the time limit for all the remaining ones. How do I improve the running time/ time complexity of the code?

P.S. This may seem like an `xy problem`, so alternative solutions are welcome :)

Comment: You do a lot of storing and copying. Would it match the goal to just output word by word, interleaved by appropriate whitespace? I.e. do not return vectors to be printed elsewhere, just print. Otherwise always attack nested loops first for improving speed.

Comment: As I understand it, the number of lines does not need to be known. I get the impression that the job can be done by never looking at more than the words which fill the current line.

Comment: In addition, for efficiency, avoid functions like `erase` ...

Comment: @Damien, `erase` has been used just once for each statement, to remove the extra space which gets added at the end. Does that still affect the performance a lot?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 in this case not effectively

Comment: @Yunnosch, That's a great alternative. How do you suggest I split the given line into 2 then? The only thing that comes to my mind is printing a `\n` after 16 chars have been printed (I can use printf's return value here), and in that case, as Damien so rightly suggested, I can even get rid of `erase`. Is this approach nice?

Comment: I would say that is what I meant. Though a little more is needed, to add the approprate number of blanks, potentially a few times the slightly higher number and then a few times the lower number, between the words in one line. Also be careful with "split the given line into 2". Do not consider the list of words a line and do not assume that the result is two lines. I get the impression that the resulting number of lines is indeterminate, possibly many.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I just wrote a Python code for the algorithm you suggested, but I can't seem to find a way to add extra spaces. Can you help? (Do I edit this question, or do I post a new one?)

Comment: Python? I thought we are discussing C++.

Comment: Nope, Your algorithm's implementation was a lot easier in python. I will try to write a C++ one though if you want :)

Comment: It seems to still be the same question, no problem. But very good style to keep an eye on when the question has left the original. I do not know what you mean by "adding extra spaces". I'd just output the right number of space between outputting words.

Comment: RE: I'd just output the right number of space between outputting words 

------------------------

exactly the issue. I am not able to figure that number

Comment: RE: But very good style to keep an eye on when the question has left the original. Usually do as I keep on getting tagged about the XY problem ;)

Comment: Generally I woudl do: Scan the list to determine the sum of lengths (each increased by 1 for at least one blank between words). When the sum is more than the desired line length, subtract the length of the last word. Determine difference between remaining sum and desired length. Divide by number of collected words. Then output first word, calculated number of blanks, next word, repeat until long enough. Test. There will be some errors when the number of blanks is not integer. Think about how to fix that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216221/discussion-between-d4rk4ng31-and-yunnosch).

Comment: Fix should roughly be: Round down, multiply by number of words. Determine difference to desired length. For that many words output an additional blank, then output only the rounded down.

Comment: I feel like this would be better placed on Code Review, since it's working code that you want to optimise, not broken code that you want to fix. That's typically more on-topic there than here.

Comment: @underscore_d You are kind of right, "optimise this" would be more of a revie question. But I see it this way. The approach is wrong (as often in case of TLEs). The change needs to replace the counting by predicting, in order to not need storing vectors of words in lines. I.e. this is an algorithm question based on a [mre] of a quasi-brute-force solution. Consider it a realtime requirement. I.e. the shown code is broken in only getting the text right but fails the timing requirement. Broken code is not on-topic for a review, but is on topic here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked problem statement starts with

> Given an array of words and a width maxWidth

In the posted code the function `justifiedText` first traverses to vector passed as a parameter as if it is composed by lines of multiple words, extracted and copied into a new vector (using `stringstream` temporaries).

Every string in the returned vector is composed appending the words until it's too big, then the last word is *erased* and spaces are *inserted* or appended.

That's a lot of unnecessary copies and modification.

Some can be saved by first calculating the needed spaces and then coping *only* the words that fit into a line at the right offset.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Helper function which copies the elements of a range into a destination object
// spaced by the result of a given function. The destination must be big enough.
template< class InputIt, class Dest, class Func >
void copy_spaced( InputIt first, InputIt last
                , Dest& dest
                , Func offset )
{
    auto src = first;
    auto it = std::copy(src->cbegin(), src->cend(), dest.begin());
    while ( ++src != last )
    {
        it = std::copy( src->cbegin(), src->cend()
                      , it + offset(std::distance(first, src)) );
    }
}

// As stated, the input is a vector of single words and a width
auto justify_lines( std::vector<std::string> const& words
                  , size_t width )
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    auto first = words.cbegin();
    auto it = first;

    // Accumulate the number of chars in the words.
    size_t count{};
    // Minimum number of spaces between each word.
    size_t min_spaces{};

    while ( it != words.cend() )
    {
        // Check if the current word can be added to the current line
        if ( count + it->size() + min_spaces > width )
        {
            if ( it->size() > width ) {
                std::cerr << "This word is too big: " << *it << '\n';
                return result;
            }

            // Copy the words only when the line is full. Start by adding an "empty"
            // line to the vector of justified lines.
            result.emplace_back(width, ' ');
            size_t n_spaces = width - count;
            size_t n_words = std::distance(first, it);

            // A single word is left justified.
            if ( n_words <= 1 )
            {
                std::copy(first->cbegin(), first->cend(), result.back().begin());
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise the strategy is to spread the spaces as evenly as possible.
                size_t n_intervals = n_words - 1;
                auto calc_offset = [ offset = n_spaces / n_intervals
                                   , limit = n_spaces % n_intervals ] (size_t i) {
                    return i <= limit ? offset + 1 : offset;
                };
                copy_spaced(first, it, result.back(), calc_offset);
            }
            // We need to reset the counters, but the current word shouldn't be skipped.
            min_spaces = 0;
            count = it->size();
            first = it++;
        }
        else {
            count += it->size();
            ++min_spaces;
            ++it;
        }
    }
    // The last line is justified to the left.
    if ( first != it )
    {
        result.emplace_back(width, ' ');
        copy_spaced(first, it, result.back(), []([[maybe_unused]]size_t i){ return 1; });
    }

    return result;
}
```

[Test](https://godbolt.org/z/7AwC9s).